# Google API for Python

Tags: python, gmail, google-api

I want to exploit Google services like Gmail, maps, search, buzz from Python on the client side. Anyone who has any experience working with any Library / Toolkit, please suggest me some

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about [Google's very own libary](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/)?

[This](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/SupportedApis) is the list of supported API's. As for e-mail, I would stick with POP3 / IMAP / SMTP...

Comment: Yeah... i checked out the documentation for that. Just wanted to have some reviews about it and to know about other similar libraries people use to get the work done.

And i hope that its inability to support anything above version 2.7 won't be a big problem, is it?

Comment: @Shatu: 2.7 is the latest in the python 2.x branch, so it's reasonably up to date unless you insist on using python3.

Comment: Hi @mac, I don't seem to find any source in the links regarding the Gmail API.

Comment: @JimmyKane - Indeed, this is why I recommended to use IMAP/SMTP in my original answer.  I don't really think a gmail API ever existed, as my understanding is that all functionality provided by gmail is in fact simply IMAP (this is why desktop mail clients can tag/untag correctly the messages, for example). Hope this clarify the issue! :)

Comment: You are right to use googles own library... It looks better than the other stuff I found. I think you may want this url now though, the one you posted actually no longer contains the library: https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client

Comment: Also I might as well add an easy way to find the docs in case anyone wants them. Right here: http://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/index.html